# Can I tell python to put an existing figure in a new figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Creating a certain plot is a lot of work, so I would like to automate this by create a function `f()` that returns a figure.

I would like to call this function so that I can put the result in a subplot.  Is there anyway I can do this?  Below is some psuedo code explaining what I mean

```
figure_of_interest = f()

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 4,cols = 1)

ax[1].replace_with(figure_of_interest)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750333/how-do-i-include-a-matplotlib-figure-object-as-subplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980915/embed-matplotlib-figure-in-larger-figure).

Short answer: It is not possible.

But you can always modify the axes instance or use a function to create/modify the current axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def test():
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)

    # With subplots
    fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
    plot(x, x, ax1)
    plot(x, x*x, ax2)

    # Another Figure without using axes
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    plot(x, np.exp(x))

    plt.show()

def plot(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)
    return line

test()
```