# Add subplots to matplotlib figure after creation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a figure with 2x2 subplots. Then with some input from the user (on a different thread), the figure changes to MxN group of sub plots without creating another figure box. Is this possible?

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(222)
threadedPlotShow(ax, x, y) #in a different thread, shows figure with xy on each

#wait for user input
m = raw_input("enter rows")
n = raw_input("enter cols")

update_figure(x,y,M,N,fig)

def update_figure(self, x, y, M, N, fig):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(nrows=M,ncols=N, index=M+N+1)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    plt.draw()
```

These posts do not help because it creates new figures (at least in my implementation, if they should't let me know and I will keep trying):
[Dynamically add/create subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319796/dynamically-add-create-subplots-in-matplotlib)

[matplotlib dynamic number of subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159397/matplotlib-dynamic-number-of-subplot)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why those posts do not help? What is different in your case. It seems from the outset at least, that what you require is a combination of those posts.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322009/can-i-tell-python-to-put-an-existing-figure-in-a-new-figure

Comment: @JoeyMallone I tried the combo and I got new figures each iteration. I went through the docs and came up with this example I added and its not working... I will now go back and try the combo again

Comment: @doctorlove I don't understand that example

Comment: I updated matplotlib from 2.0.2 to 3.0.x and used gridspec and it works... Should I delete question? or answer it?

Comment: I think answering it is sensible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user inputs which data to plot, then M,N are auto generated. We clear figure, add gridpsec, add subplot, plot data. Same figure is reused, just new data each time.

```
clear_figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(M, N, wspace=0.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[M,N])
ax.plot(x,y)
```